# Remove all data from c3js chart

Tags: c3.js

How all data can be removed from chart without pointing the names of the data-sets?
I can't use that way because my data that is populated in the chart is dynamically created.
This is the way of removing by pointing the data-set name:

```
chart.unload({
    ids: ['data1', 'data2']                             
});
```

There is command that removes all of the data? Or i need to recreate the whole chart?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to C3.js documentation for `.unload()` function :

> If no argument is given, all of targets will be toggles.

Have you tried that ?

If you want to delete the C3 object you can also do a simple `.destroy()` or a `.flush()` to force the redraw.

Comment: Yeah, unload without any arguments have do the trick! Just calling chart.unload(); have removed all of the data from the chart. Thanks